# Cannot trigger pipeline for my default (main) branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

I have been racking my brain around this and I feel like I am going nowhere. I have a project whose code is hosted on Gitlab. My project has two branches, `develop` and `main`. I make changes on my `develop` branch, push these changes which updates my staging instance. When I am ready to deploy live changes, I merge with `main` which is meant to trigger a deployment to my live instance. This is my `gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
default:
  image: docker:19.03.10
  tags:
    - docker
    
.deployment_script: &deployment_script
  - echo "Starting deployment to ECS ..."
  - echo "So many lines here that deploy code to aws ecs"

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  REPOSITORY_URL: **********.dkr.ecr.**-****-*.amazonaws.com/********/****

before_script:
  - echo "Creating image tag ..."
  - IMAGE_TAG="$(echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA | head -c 8)"

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo $DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT ...
    - echo "The script here build my docker container and publishes to aws ecr"
    - echo "Build is only meant to be ran when pushing to develop"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"'
      when: always        

deploy-staging:
  environment: staging
  dependencies:
    - "build"
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  script:
    - *deployment_script
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"'
      when: manual

deploy-production:
  environment: production
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  script:
    - *deployment_script
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
      when: manual
```

Every time I deploy to the  `develop` branch, the pipelines are triggered and I successfully deploy my staging application. However, no matter how many times I push to `main`, nothing is triggered. I have no idea why. I hope someone can point me in the right direction too figure this out.

Comment: Does the job get created at least? Are you seeing some kind of error?

Comment: That's the weird thing, there is no error of any kind. Nothing in jobs or pipelines to even indicate there is a job that needs to be ran.

Comment: That is strange, I would check the repo/group configuration. Go to Settings->CI/CD and verify that "CI/CD configuration file" is pointing to `gitlab-ci.yml`.

Comment: Rules look fine, but when I lint this configuration, it fails validation because `deploy-production` and `deploy-staging` defines no `stage:` (meaning it uses that stage `test`, which is not defined). But otherwise, seems like it is correct based on your desired behavior.